# How to track down cause of slow app performance for some users but not all

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What are some suggestions for tracking down those instances where one or two users are experiencing very slow performance with an app that connects to a few databases on your network.

I've already identified and added a lot of missing indexes.

There is a maintenance plan that rebuilds all indexes every week.

At the time one user experiencing the slowness, others were not and there were no blocks on either SQL Server (using `sp_who2`)

Next up will be to do some perfmon to capture some different counters to see if we have i/o issues.

Actually, today I did see where there are 2 more new missing indexes, so that might have something to do with it.

Comment: I would use SQL profiler (I think it's still called that) to identify exactly which queries are causing the slow performance.

Comment: I suppose I could do that, but I tend to use profiler to catch the details of exactly what commands and their details that are coming across, and do this when I know which application is about to start up.  However, I am looking for kind of a check list of things to go through when a few users are reporting slow performance.  A check list such as: